# How to keep track of columns after encoding categorical variables?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I am wondering how I can keep track of the original columns of a dataset once I perform data preprocessing on it?

In the below code `df_columns` would tell me that column `0` in `df_array` is `A`, column `1` is `B` and so forth...

However when once I encode categorical column `B` `df_columns` is no longer valid for keeping track of `df_dummies`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

animal = ['dog','cat','horse']

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.rand(9),
                   'B': [animal[np.random.randint(3)] for i in range(9)],
                   'C': np.random.rand(9),
                   'D': np.random.rand(9)})

df_array = df.values
df_columns = df.columns

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
ct = ColumnTransformer([('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [1])], remainder='passthrough')
df_dummies = np.array(ct.fit_transform(df_array), dtype=np.float)
```

The solution should be agnostic of the position of the categorical column... be it `A`, `B`, `C` or `D`. I can do the grunt work and keep updating the `df_columns` dictionary... but it wouldn't be elegant or "pythonic"

Furthermore... how would the solution look to keep track of what the categoricals mean? {0,0,1} would be cat, {0,1,0} would be dog and so on?

PS - I am aware of the dummy variable trap and will take `df_dummies[:,1:]` when I actually use it to train my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm if future data sets will continue to have the same column names? If I got your question correctly, all that you will need to do is save `df_columns` from the original data frame and use it to reindex your new dataframe.

```
new_df_reindexed = new_df[df_columns]
```

To answer your other questions, you can one-hot encode your data using `get_dummies()` from pandas. Use the `drop_first` parameter to drop one of the generated column values and avoid the dummy variable trap. Also, save the column list of the one-hot-encoded data frame.

To ensure that you new / testing / holdout data set has the same column definition as that used in model training,

- First use `get_dummies()` to one-hot-encode the new data set.
- Use pandas `reindex` to bring the new dataframe into the same structure as the one used in model training - `df.reindex(columns=train_one_hot_encode_col_list, axis="columns")`.
- The above will create dummy variable columns for categorical column values in the training data set that are not present in the categorical columns of the new data set.
- Finally, use the above method to remove any columns in the new data set that are not present in the old data set - `test_df_reindexed = test_df_onehotencode[train_one_hot_encode_col_list]`

If you follow these steps, you can completely rely on the list of original column names, and will not need to track column positions or categorical value definitions.

I would also advice you to read the below for further reference:
One-hot encoding in pandas - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html
Column re-indexing - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html

Comment: Hey @RealRageDontQuit - I have edited my response to include coding examples, as well as further resources for helpful pandas functions. Does this answer your question? I assumed that you want to save column definitions from model training and then apply them on testing data sets as well as future unseen data. However, let me know if I missed anything.